# Manipular arquivos .srt com PHP

Tags: php, laravel

estou desenvolvendo um projeto em Laravel 8 e esse projeto consiste em um sistema de gerenciamento de legendas em SRT. No mundo da legendagem as equipes dividem um legenda inteira (arquivo srt) em varios slots. Em outras palavras, um arquivo em srt é dividido em vários arquivos srt para que cada membro da equipe fique responsável com sua parte em questão. Dito isso, eu queria achar uma solução para que eu pudesse upar o arquivo inteiro no sistema, escolher o número de slots em que ele seria dividido e assim gerar vários arquivos srt (derivado do principal/inteiro que upei).

Se eu fizer isso, evitaria que eu dividisse o arquivo manualmente e tivesse que upar 1 por 1.

Um arquivo srt segue esse padrão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele tem um tipo de ID (numeração), tempo inicial/final e a legenda. Porém, a legenda pode variar entre 1 a 2 linhas, o que quebra um pouco o padrão.

Eu pensei em fazer as contagens das linhas e depois manipular baseado no padrão, mas se tornaria inviável porque algumas possuem 1 ou 2 linhas como mencionei anteriormente. Ex.:

```js
<?php
$arquivo = fopen('meuarquivo.srt','r');
if ($arquivo == false) die('Não foi possível abrir o arquivo.');
while(true) {
    $linha = fgets($arquivo);
    if ($linha==null) break;
    echo $linha;
}
fclose($arquivo);
?>
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar com uma sugestão de como poderia manipular isso em PHP e DB?

Comment: você pode ta utilizando o ```RegExp``` para está incluindo os formatos ou até mesmo verificando esses *id* sem precisar saber onde ta posicionado os valores em cada linha

Comment: É um padrão essa separação de linha em branco? Se sim, talvez de para fazer um `explode` nos "\n\n", mais ou menos isso `explode("\n\n", file_get_contents('arquivo.srt'));` o resultado deve ser um array onde cada elemento é um slot

Comment: De antemão, obrigado pelas respostas. Isso, é um padrão essa separação de linha em branca. Show de bola a ideia, irei fazer uns teste para ver se dará certo.